# Detect if string begins by x digits number in php

Tags: php, regex

How can I rename file if it begins by `5` digits ?

This is what I tried:

```
$filename = '156272_abc.png';
$string = PREG_REPLACE("/[^0-9]i5/", '', $filename);
```

But it doesn't work.

Could you please point me in the right direction ?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you putting `i5` in there?

Comment: @Snow because I'm new and after reading some tutorials I can't apply them to my example. Sorry for my lack of experience but I don't think your `-1` is really relevant to help me.

Comment: What is the replacement name should there be a match?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I would need something like `156272.png`. But sometimes, I will have some `.jpg` as well.

Comment: `"/^[0-9]{5}/"`

Comment: *"but I don't think your -1 is really relevant to help me"* - You can't be 100% certain that they downvoted you and accusing someone like that. For all we know, it could have been me; but alas... it wasn't.

Comment: Do you want to rename the whole file string, or simply the 5 digits part?

Comment: Exactly 5 digits or *at least* 5 digits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is this:

```
$filename = '156272_abc.png';
$replacement = preg_replace("/^(\d{5,}).*(\.[^.]+)$/", "$1$2", $filename);
```

This will match any filename beginning with five or more digits, and replace with just the leading digits, followed by the extension.